# Is there a feature to export a layout with dimensions?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design, affinity-designer

I'm creating a layout for a website with Affinity Designer. Is there a feature in Affinity Designer (or Photoshop/Illustrator) to somehow export a design generating all dimensions into the target file, so that a frontend developer can easily see which dimensions to use when building it? If not, how do you guys handle this problem?

Comment: Yes this can be done but software that do this are not common in graphic design. But yeah most mechanical engineers have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use collaboration softwares like

Zeplin, Invision etc.

They are designed for this purpose to make it easier for developers to code the exact design that designer did.

Not only they will show you the dimensions, but also some basic codes (Mostly CSS).

Answer (score 1):

Just change the units on the program from "cm" or "in" to pixels and work in real size.

Not only the export will be o the real dimension, but also the original file.